# SQL inserting into temporary table else if bitwise manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using an SQL query to insert into a temporary table. I have a column named "Flag" that I want to do bitwise "OR" on based on conditions, and I want to do it multiple times within the SQL query... so in terms of pseudo code.

```
select
       if(@Date not between a.beginDate and isnull(a.endDate,@Date)
          Flag | 1
       else if (@Date not between b.beginDate and isnull(b.endDate,@Date)
          Flag | 2
       else if (@Date not between c.beginDate and isnull(c.endDate,@Date)
          Flag | 4
       etc.
```

Is this even possible? I was using separate update statements on the temporary table after the query to do this and it works, but I was told it can be done with case statements within the query.

In the simplest case:

```
Table A             Table B            Table C
Flag                Name               Name
0                   "Scott"            "Joe"

If table B name is "Scott"
Flag | 1 = 1

if table C name is "Joe"
Flag | 2 = 2
```

So flag should be 3 in the temporary table afterwards.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I the simplest case: 
`code`
        Table A                 Table B                          Table C
Flag                                Name                           Name
0                                     "Scott"                           "Joe"
`code`
If table B name is "Scott"
Flag | 1 = 1

if table C name is "Joe"
Flag | 2 = 2

So flag should be 3 in the temp table afterwards

Comment: It would be better to *not* store multiple facts in a single column. That's not the SQL way.

Comment: Don't use bitfields. Just don't do it. I have experience maintaining a database that used them and it's really painful. Use individual `BIT NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: A lot of our tables use a single column and bitwise operations to represent error flags, so.... the 8th bit of the Flag integer would represent a file failing to load. It's a pre-existing system that's heavily used. Adding four more columns would cause a lot of changes in about 5 SPs, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [bitwise OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql) like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN @Date NOT BETWEEN a.beginDate AND ISNULL(a.endDate,@Date) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END 
| CASE WHEN @Date NOT BETWEEN b.beginDate AND ISNULL(b.endDate,@Date) THEN 2  ELSE 0 END 
| CASE WHEN @Date NOT BETWEEN c.beginDate AND ISNULL(c.endDate,@Date) THEN 4  ELSE 0 END 
AS Flag
FROM 
....
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't know you could do bitwise operations between case statements. Thanks!